# Is it possible to dojo.require() in a Django widget?

Tags: django, dojo

Django allows users to specify custom widget media like so...

```
class CalendarWidget(forms.TextInput):
    class Media:
        js = ('animations.js', 'actions.js')
```

As the example at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/media/#media-as-a-static-definition shows, the generated media looks like...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.example.com/animations.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://media.example.com/actions.js"></script>
```

The problem is that I am using Dojo and the  requirement for my widget is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");    
</script>
```

How can I generate this script tag via a Django form field widget? Right now it seems impossible... which means I can't use Django's sweet Form setup or I need to switch my Javascript framework. Please help me do neither!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways: either reate a `.js` file which only contains the require, then add it to the `js` list: `js = [ …, 'dojo_require_TextBox.js' ]`, or prefix the widget with the `<script />` tag by overriding render in your widget:

```
def render(self, *args):
    result = super(MyWidget, self).render(*args)
    return "<script>dojo.require(…)</script>" + result
```

Comment: Overriding render() solved the problem above and many others for me! I've been trying to do something like this but I never made it to render(). THANK YOU!